# How to get a respose from a localhost url exactly http://localhost:8888/

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have two projects setting up Springboot in it, now, I am going to run these two springboot on eclipse, I set up the port 8888 for projectB.
[image]
Here is my projectB controller with RequestMapping.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String test() {
    return "testtesttest";
}
```

I need to call a url from jquery method that url is to read the respose from a controller in projectB.

how can I call this url ??
 I tried "http://localhost:8888/test"  and "http://127.0.0.1:8888/test"
 but I did not get anything from the response.

The error shows up as :
[image]

please give me the solution for this

very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code in your application's main class. This configures your web mvc cors mapping to allow request from " * "

```
   @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application {

    @Configuration
        public class MyConfiguration {
            @Bean
            public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
                return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                        logger.info("Added CORS config");
                        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").maxAge(3600);
                    }
                };
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply,   I will keep your answer in my note.   Actually, I added CrossOrigin annotation on my controller, seems it  solves the problem.